# User in Administrators group has not the same rights as Administrator (Win 2022 R2) for fresh build

Tags: users, local, windows-server-2022

We've been having the issue where a domain user in the builtin\Administrators group, does not have the same access as Administrator, but only on fresh builds of server 2022.  Servers that we upgraded from either 2008 or 2012 to 2022 do not have this issue.

UAC is enabled on the upgrade servers and the two below local policies are set as default

User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account (disabled by default)
User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode (enabled by default)

Any new user added to the builtin\Administrators group on these upgrade servers has same access as Administrator.

It only is on fresh server 2022 builds that we have to disable the "Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" policy for them to have the same access, and this is something we do not want to do.

The most frustrating part in this, is on these fresh builds, the user in the builtin\Administrators, only has New --> Folder when right clicking anywhere they don't own.  None of the other context menu items like new text document are there.